# How to specify my dbName in mongodb connection string with authentication?

Tags: mongodb

In my express/mongoose app, say I have multiple dbs in the same mongodb server, one is xxx. If I don't have authenticaion, my connection string looks like

```
mongodb://myserver.cloudappserver.net/xxx
```

which works great. Now, I added authentication as

```
use admin
db.createUser({user:"admin",pwd:"yyy",roles:[{role:"root",db:"admin"}]});
```

Based on documentation, my connection string should look like

```
mongodb://admin:yyy@myserver.cloudappserver.net/admin
```

Now, my question is how do I specify the db "xxx" I want to work with?

Comment: It depends. What driver are you using? Some allow you yo specify the database on the connection string, and just authenticate to `admin`. Some like C# for example, actually expect no database on the connection string at all, and you actually select the database using the provided API instead.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out based on [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3905)... the connection string should look like this

```
mongodb://admin:yyy@myserver.cloudappserver.net/xxx?authSource=admin
```